# Cannot delete array

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I cannot figure out how to delete and array.

```
int* array = new int[5];
```

I tried to delete the array like this

```
delete array[5];
```

but I get an error: cannot delete expression of type 'int'

I also tried

```
delete [5]array;
```

but I got an error: error: expected expression

How do I delete an array? I don't know what else to do?

Thanks in advance for any help. It is very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to learn C++ and its syntax based on guessing. That does not work. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: Just about *any* book should have told you how to do it. If you don't have one, then consider [this list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: Also, dynamic allocation using `new` and `delete` is good to know and learn, but once you do know how to use them, they're often not needed. In your example, if you want a "dynamic array" of `int` elements, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), as in `std::vector<int> array(5);` which defines `array` to be a vector of five elements.

Comment: ` delete[] array;`

Comment: Sorry I tried searching in search bar but did not see anything. Should I delete this?

Comment: Thank you programmer dude. I do not have a book though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
delete [] array;   // Delete an array
array = 0;      // Clear array to prevent using invalid memory reference
```

Answer (score 1):

try `delete []array;` that would do.
array is one pointer pointing to the beginning of the 5-element dynamic-array so you only have to delete one pointer.

Comment: It’s not a dynamic pointer. It’s a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. A dynamic pointer would be a pointer created on the heap.

Comment: You don't delete pointers, you delete the things they point to. It's an important distinction, in particular to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is [`delete []array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6227113.aspx). You do not need to specify the size when calling delete.